# PHP создание объектов

Tags: php, база-данных, объекты

Как создать объект один раз за все время работы приложения?
Есть точка входа, там хочу создать объект DataBase.

```
$db = new DataBase($parameters);
```

Во всех остальных файлах хочу чтоб можно было просто делать так:

```
$db->select($query);
```

Answer (score 3):

Возможно вам нужен паттерн [Singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

```
class DB {
  private function __construct(){} // запрет new DB()
  private function __wake(){}      // запрет unserialize
  private function __clone(){}     // запрет clone $db;
  private static $db = null;
  public static function get($params) {
    return self::$db ?: self::$db = new self();
  }
  public function setup($params) {/*...*/}
}
```

Использование:

```
DB::get()->setup($config);
...
DB::get()->select(...);
```

---

Одна из проблем этого паттерна в том, что иногда нам может понадобиться второе соединение - придётся как-то с этим бороться.

Также, по сути это создание зависимости от глобального контекста. Неочевидно, какие классы теперь зависят от DB.

Намного лучше просто создать объект и передавать его всем, кто в нём нуждается([DI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)).

Comment: Мне кажется, правильней использовать, все же, название Singleton. Чисто с точки зрения восприятия. Понятно, что он переводится, как "одиночка", но ведь мы (и Вы) используем и, например, слово "паттерн", а не шаблон (как было бы в переводе).

Comment: В общем согласен..

Comment: однако, вариант перевода в дополнение можно было и оставить, мало ли кто не знает как переводится )

Comment: @teran, названия статьи на википедии по ссылке достаточно :)

Comment: @vp_arth, да, пардоньте, не обратил внимания :) А для разных подключений надо их именовать, и хранить экземплры не простом поле, а в массиве, получая через `DB::get('default')` и т.п.

Comment: @teran, отсутствия явной зависимости достаточно, чтобы не пользоваться синглтоном для базы. Использую его только для действительно глобальных вещей, вроде глобального конфига.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте статическую переменную класса для хранения подключения к бд и почитайте по поводу шаблона singleton

Comment: какой объемный и содержательный ответ!

Comment: Какой полезный комментарий!